# Creating new columns from long strings split into 300 substrings?

Tags: r, string

I have a column containing 1200 character strings. In each one, every four character group is hexadecimal for a number. i.e. 300 numbers in hexadecimal crammed into a 1200 character string, in every row. I need to get each number out into decimal, and into its own column (300 new columns) named 1-300.
Here's what I've figured out so far:

```
  Data.frame:
                      BigString
                 [1]  0043003E803C0041004A...(etc...)
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
decimal.fours <- function(x) {
    strtoi(substring(BigString[x], seq(1,1197,4), seq(4,1197,4)), 16L)
}
decimal.fours(1)
[1] 283   291   239   177 ...
```

But now I'm stuck. How can I output these individual number, (and the remaining 296, into new columns? I have fifty total rows/strings. It would be great to do them all at once, i.e. 300 new columns, containing split up substrings from 50 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory tidyverse example:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Setup some data

```
set.seed(1492)

bet <- c(0:9, LETTERS[1:6]) # alphabet for hex digit sequences
i <- 8                      # number of rows
n <- 10                     # number of 4-hex-digit sequences

df <- data_frame(
   some_other_col=LETTERS[1:i],
   big_str=map_chr(1:i, ~sample(bet, 4*n, replace=TRUE) %>% paste0(collapse=""))
)

df
## # A tibble: 8 × 2
##   some_other_col                                  big_str
##            <chr>                                    <chr>
## 1              A 432100D86CAA388C15AEA6291E985F2FD3FB6104
## 2              B BC2673D112925EBBB3FD175837AF7176C39B4888
## 3              C B4E99FDAABA47515EADA786715E811EE0502ABE8
## 4              D 64E622D7037D35DE6ADC40D0380E1DC12D753CBC
## 5              E CF7CDD7BBC610443A8D8FCFD896CA9730673B181
## 6              F ED86AEE8A7B65F843200B823CFBD17E9F3CA4EEF
## 7              G 2B9BCB73941228C501F937DA8E6EF033B5DD31F6
## 8              H 40823BBBFDF9B14839B7A95B6E317EBA9B016ED5
```

Do the manipulation

```
read_fwf(paste0(df$big_str, collapse="\n"),
         fwf_widths(rep(4, n)),
         col_types=paste0(rep("c", n), collapse="")) %>%
  mutate_all(strtoi, base=16) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  select(some_other_col, everything(), -big_str)
## # A tibble: 8 × 11
##   some_other_col    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
##            <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1              A 17185   216 27818 14476  5550 42537  7832 24367 54267
## 2              B 48166 29649  4754 24251 46077  5976 14255 29046 50075
## 3              C 46313 40922 43940 29973 60122 30823  5608  4590  1282
## 4              D 25830  8919   893 13790 27356 16592 14350  7617 11637
## 5              E 53116 56699 48225  1091 43224 64765 35180 43379  1651
## 6              F 60806 44776 42934 24452 12800 47139 53181  6121 62410
## 7              G 11163 52083 37906 10437   505 14298 36462 61491 46557
## 8              H 16514 15291 65017 45384 14775 43355 28209 32442 39681
## # ... with 1 more variables: X10 <int>
```

Comment: I'm curious - why mix nested functions and pipes? If you're piping, why not: `df$big_str %>% paste0(collapse="\n") %>% read_fwf(...` ?

Comment: Go for it if it works better for you. I just got done presenting https://github.com/hrbrmstr/rstudioconf2017 at rstudio::conf(2017L) and don't believe I've violated any of my own personal "guidelines" for piping here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read.fwf` which read in files with fixed width for each column:

```
# an example vector of big strings
BigString = c("0043003E803C0041004A", "0043003E803C0041004A", "0043003E803C0041004A")

n = 5                  # n is the number of columns for your result(300 for your real case)
as.data.frame(
      lapply(read.fwf(file = textConnection(BigString), 
                      widths = rep(4, n), 
                      colClasses = "character"), 
             strtoi, base = 16))

#  V1 V2    V3 V4 V5
#1 67 62 32828 65 74
#2 67 62 32828 65 74
#3 67 62 32828 65 74
```

---

If you'd like to keep the `decimal.hours` function, you can modify it as follows and call `lapply` to convert your bigStrings to list of integers which can be further converted to data.frame with `do.call(rbind, ...)` pattern:

```
decimal.fours <- function(x) {
    strtoi(substring(x, seq(1,1197,4), seq(4,1197,4)), 16L)
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(BigString, decimal.fours))
```

Answer (score 1):

just a try using base-R

```
BigString = c("0043003E803C0041004A", "0043003E803C0041004A", "0043003E803C0041004A")
df = data.frame(BigString)


t(sapply(df$BigString, function(x) strtoi(substring(x, seq(1, 297, 4)[1:5],
                                                    seq(4, 300, 4)[1:5]), base = 16)))
#     [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   67   62 32828   65   74
#[2,]   67   62 32828   65   74
#[3,]   67   62 32828   65   74

# you can set the columns together at the end using `paste0("new_col", 1:300)` 
# [1:5] was just used for this example, because i had strings of length 20cahr
```